# Add functionality to a pure virtual function in C++?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I wish to have a pure virtual function, but I need to guarantee that all implementations of it include some bookkeeping.

Here is a workaround that achieves what I want, but it is clunky.

Is there a better approach? If not, is there a naming convention for a function like actually_do_it()?

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual void do_it() final
  {
    bookkeeping();
    actually_do_it();
  }

protected:
  virtual void actually_do_it() = 0;

private:
  void bookkeeping() {}
};

class B : public A
{
  void actually_do_it() {}
};

...

B b;
b.do_it();
```

Comment: This seems to be doing it pretty well? What else do you want here?

Comment: Something like `do_it_impl` might be a good a name

Comment: Note that you *can* provide an implementation for a pure virtual function and call it from derived classes. Maybe that's what you want for providing that common functionality?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Could you post an example of that approach please?

Comment: @lemon `class base { virtual void f() = 0;` then implement as `void base::f() { std::cout << "base\n"; }` then in derived class member call `base::f();`. Derived classes are required to implement `f` since it is pure/abstract, but it still has an implementation that derived functions can call.

Comment: I think NVI is the better approach.

Comment: @sweenish I never said it was a *good* approach, I merely mentioned it as an available option.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I see how my comment can be taken that way. All I wanted to do was throw my hat in the opinion-ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better approach? If not, is there a naming convention for a function like actually_do_it()?

"better" is purely subjective unless you define what "better" means. You approach is widely accepted and known as the Template Method Pattern (see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

I have seen it more commonly used when a method consists of several steps and the derived classes can customize the individual steps, but your use case is just as valid.